# wcf router doesn't expose metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

There are about 30 wcf services and we use the wcf router to distribute the requests from client. The wcf services are hosted by windows service. When we put the client and service in the same computer, the client and service can contact to each other. However, when they are in the different machines, the client can't contact the service. I used wcftestclient to test the service also and it always can't add the service, or can't add the service if I use a added client project to test it.  All the individual service use net.pipe and router uses net.tcp if the service is in a different machine from the client. I have been working on this for a couple of weeks and the problem is still there. Can anybody point out what could be possibly wrong with it? Thanks a lot!

We have a setting configuration file for end users to input the name of the service server address. The port number will be in the setting file also.

```
    if (!this._issinglecomputer)
        {
            // now add protocol conversion router
            Uri routerbaseaddress = new Uri(publicbaseaddress, "router");
            _routingsvchost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RoutingService), routerbaseaddress);
            _routingsvchostmex = new ServiceHost(typeof (RoutingService), new Uri(routerbaseaddress, "mex"));

            // add the endpoint the router will use to receive service requests
            // we use IDuplexSessionRouter to support a variety of one-way and two-way calls
            _routingsvchost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDuplexSessionRouter), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), "");
            _routingsvchostmex.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDuplexSessionRouter), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(), "mex");

            // add routing config
            RoutingConfiguration rc = new RoutingConfiguration();

            // loop over all the hosted interfaces and add the entries to the routing table
            foreach (IWcfServiceLibrary sl in wcfServiceLibraries)
            {
                foreach (IWcfServiceConfig config in sl.WcfServiceConfigs)
                {
                    string routedservice = config.WcfService.ServiceClassName.Split('.').Last();
                    var contract = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(ISimplexDatagramRouter));
                    var client = new ServiceEndpoint(contract, new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/" + routedservice));
                    var ea = new EndpointAddress(routerbaseaddress.AbsoluteUri.ToString() + "/" + routedservice);
                    rc.FilterTable.Add(new EndpointAddressMessageFilter(ea, false), new List<ServiceEndpoint>() { client });
                }
            }

            _routingsvchost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new RoutingBehavior(rc));
            _routingsvchostmex.Description.Behaviors.Add(new RoutingBehavior(rc));

            _routingsvchost.Open();
            _routingsvchostmex.Open();


            LoggingService.Logger.Info(string.Format("It is now routing services at {0}", routerbaseaddress.AbsoluteUri));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another service behavior and turn on HttpGetEnabled property.

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior b = new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true };
b.HttpGetUrl = myMetadataUri;
routingsvchost.Description.Behaviors.Add(b);
```

Comment: I tried it and it still has the problem. I wonder if it could come from other places other than configuration part.